# fragments, android:zAdjustment (z order) and animations

Tags: android-fragments, android-animation

I'm using the support library. Now, I want to have a fragment shifting in from the bottom, moving OVER the previous one.

For this I use this to keep the previous fragment (the one that is being slided over) visible until the new fragment is in its place:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
   android:duration="2500"
   android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

this is animation used for the new fragment to slide in from bottom:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
        android:zAdjustment="top"/>
```

I've put the z adjustment to bottom and top for both, but still the 'bottom' animation is still on top of the new fragment! I have put the duration to 2500 for testing and it stays on top for the whole time.

Does zAdjustment not work for fragment animations?

Comment: Did you find any way to force the previous fragment to appear below the appearing fragment?

Comment: I am not sure what I did to get this working. Should have to check my code but not possible at this time.

Comment: Where you able to somehow adjust the z-index in fragment animations? It will be very helpful if you share with us.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Have you found a way to change the z-order so that the appearing fragment is on top during the .replace() transition?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know how I ended up with this. It's been too long for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2xVkWWY2oBU) google group thread Z adjustment only works for window animations.

"The Z adjustment only works for window animations.  I thought this was documented, but apparently not."
-- Dianne Hackborn (Android framework engineer)

Answer (score 6):

You can override the `onCreateAnimation` method and for any animations you can check what animation is currently running and if you need it to be on top, set the Z-axis from there.

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    if (nextAnim == R.anim.enter_from_right || nextAnim == R.anim.exit_to_right) {
        ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 1f)
    } else {
        ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 0f)
    }

    return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
}
```

Recommend implementing this as a base Fragment class for all your fragments.

Comment: `view` is always null for me within my `Fragment`.

Comment: This works only for Android 21+. For rest `setTranslationZ` does nothing.

Comment: `return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)` throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim) must not be null` better to make `return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, nextAnim)`

Answer (score 4):

I've also got stuck with that problem. So instead of using `transaction.replace(containerId, newFragment)` I've created two containers for fragments and now my code looks like this one

Add first fragment:

```
transaction.add(containerId1, firstFragment).commit();
```

Add second fragment with animation over the first one:

```
findViewById(containerId2).bringToFront();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up,
 R.anim.stay).remove(oldFragment).add(containerId2, newFragment).commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` as a fragments container. It automatically handles z order for animations specified in `setCustomAnimations()`