# zAdjustment="top" has no effect for button inside TableRow?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `Fragment` (using the support library, and yes I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155845/fragments-androidzadjustment-z-order-and-animations) post). Inside this fragment I have an `ImageButton` (A) inside a `TableRow` (B). I'm trying to animate `A` - expanding it, then shrinking it again. Here's the animation used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <scale
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXScale="1.25"
        android:toYScale="1.25"
        android:zAdjustment="top"/>
</set>
```

It works except that when `A` grows it is clipped by the borders of `B`. Hence, `android:zAdjustment` seems to have no effect. (`B` is necessary for this layout, so I can't change/remove it during animation.)

**Q: How do I animate my button on top of all other views?**

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12314173/451962

TL;DR: zAdjustment only works for Window animations.

Comment: Yup. This seems like the right answer!